# Merge files where there may be no data in first cell in range

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I have VBA code that was working. The files used to have some kind of data in A2 (Row 1 is headers). Now the script will skip that file if A2 is blank.

The new versions of the files only have the data I need in A2-AEC. I need to take all files located with a folder and merge them into a single spreadsheet (not multiple tabs).

I've tried looking in several sources but I haven't found anything that works.

```
Sub GatherAndMerge()
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim r As Range
Dim s As String
Const FolderToSearch = "Z:...."  'adjust as desired
s = Dir(FolderToSearch, "\*.xls?")
Do While s <> ""
    If Right(FolderToSearch, 1) <> "\" Then s = "\" & s
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderToSearch & s)
    Set r = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
    r.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset1, 0
    wb.Close False
    s = Dir(0)
Loop
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Current code.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Set the save path here in the space below between the parentheses
    'The Server is usually mapped to Z but should be verified
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("Z:\path-here")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

        'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
        'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
        'the specified range is much more than the AMMS or Techs should ever send
        Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

        'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        bookList.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean A2:AEC, that's 809 columns  of data ? Your code shows A2:IV

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GatherAndMerge()
Dim wb as workbook

dim r as range
dim s as string
const FolderToSearch = "c:\"  'adjust as desired
s = dir(foldertosearch\*.xls?")
do while s <> ""
if right(foldertosearch,1)<> "\" then  s = "\" & s
set wb = workbooks.open(foldertosearch &  s)
set r = wb.worksheets(1).usedrange.offset(1,0)
r.copy thisworkbook.worksheets(1).range("a" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0) ' there was a missing bracket here
wb.close False
s = dir(0
loop
Msgbox "Done"
End Sub
```

Written on my phone, no excel so there might be typos

Comment: I'm getting "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" on the r.copy

Comment: I'm still having issues with the copy portion
Sub GatherAndMerge()
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim r As Range
Dim s As String
Const FolderToSearch = "Z:\..."  'adjust as desired
s = Dir(FolderToSearch, "\*.xls?")
Do While s <> ""
If Right(FolderToSearch, 1) <> "\" Then s = "\" & s
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderToSearch & s)
Set r = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
r.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset1, 0
wb.Close False
s = Dir(0)
Loop
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub